# ¿Como puedo rellenar un rectangulo con una imagen con libreria GD en PHP?

Tags: php, librería, gd

necesito saber como puedo rellenar una parte de mi imagen creada con otra imagen, digamos que la parte que quiero rellenar es el cuadrado que esta marcado, estaba pensando que podría utilizarlo como un contenedor, pero no tengo nada ¿Alguna idea o recomendación de librería?

```
<?php
//Tipo de letra
$ttf = "Montague.ttf";
$verdana ="verdana.ttf";
//Obtencion de informacion
$abc = "CENTRO DE NEGOCIOS 'EMBUDO'";
//Creacion de elementos
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(2000, 1200);  
$footer=imagecreatefrompng("celebrar.png"); //Imagen de prueba
// Declaracion de colores
imagetruecolortopalette($im,false, 255); //Lets get something of the html resources
$textopie=imagecolorallocate($im,102, 102, 102);  // color de palabras pequeñas
$index = imagecolorclosest($im,0,0,0 ); // get black color
$Color_raiz = imagecolorallocate($im, 87, 35, 101); //es morado
$blanco=imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255); 
$negro=imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0,0);
//Declaracion de variables estaticas
imagestring($im, 3, 5, 5, '©Sinlimites', $textopie); // tamaño, x, y
imagestring($im, 2, 1900, 1170, 'SinLimites.com', $textopie); // tamaño, x, y
imagefttext($im,50,90,1900,1150,$negro,$verdana,"Centro de"); // tamaño, angulo, x, y
imagefttext($im,50,90,1980,1100,$negro,$verdana,"negocio:"); // tamaño, angulo, x, y
imagefttext($im,90,90,1950,750,$negro,$verdana,"669"); // tamaño, angulo, x, y
imagefttext($im,40,90,1900,285,$negro,$verdana,"inicias"); // tamaño, angulo, x, y
imagefttext($im,70,90,1980,350,$negro,$verdana,"$100"); // tamaño, angulo, x, y
imagefttext($im,50,0,500,70,$negro,$verdana,$abc); // tamaño, angulo, x, y
imagecolorset($im,$index,255,255,255); // Background color
//Declaracion de estructura basica del arbol
imagerectangle($im, 20, 100, 1820, 1180, $Color_raiz); //contenedor que necesito rellenar con una imagen

// Salida de imagen
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Lo que muestra es esto, no tengo problemas, solo necesito rellenar la parte marcada con una imagen ya precargada, acepto cualquier solución.

[image: Contenido]

Comment: te recomiendo apliamente ocupar para propósitos similares a los que tienes Javascript en lugar de PHP